# Pause fetching new messages from Azure Service Bus in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am creating an azure function using a service bus to make my API more resilient to high traffic spikes. However I am uncertain on how I should handle an offline database as the function still continues to fetch messages, eventually dead lettering messages.

**Therefore I were thinking about implementing a check during the startup class of the function to automatically shut it down before fetching any events.**

It would look something like this:

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var settings = new MongoClientSettings();
        var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
        mongoClient.StartSession();
        if(mongoCLient.Cluser.Description.State != MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.CluseterState.Connected)
            throw new Exception("Db connection failed during startup")
    }
}
```

However as I am not certain on how the trigger really works i am wondering if there might be any issues i cant foresee. Its also quite hard to test properly.

Any thoughts, knowledge or potentially other ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Turn of auto complete in host.json and If you peek the messages they will remain on the queue until you complete them. Use ServiceBusTrigger as normal but set a flag in Configure to let the trigger know the database is down. It can then return without completing the message, which will remain on the queue.

Comment: This might not be what you want as the delivery count is incremented if you leave it on the queue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#attributes
You can send it back to the queue with a re-delivery delay in the expectation the database will be back online the next time the message arrives.